# Is there a way to hide class property for swagger, but with the post request set value in c#?

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

How can I hide the class property for the swagger doc, but allow the user to set value, if he knows the property name?

I tried [JsoneIgnoreAttribute], but when I add the swagger example, again the property appears in the documentation (For adding the swagger example I used Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters).

Also, I found [IgnoreDataMember] - this one always hides, and when you set a value, it defaults the value, like null.

Comment: Have you tried the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute from the Newtonsoft.Json library or the `NotMapped` attribute from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema?

Comment: [JsoneIgnore] from Newtonsoft.Json [NotMapped] don't hide, even with a swagger example. [JsoneIgnore] from  System.Text.Json.Serialization hides, but when I add swagger example, it comes back